development of solana based stable coin e-Rupiya and e-Paisa,100 e-Paisa equals to e-Rupiya
I want to develop stable coin "e-Rupiya". theme "for the people by the people and to the people" and inclusive growth for all" Decentralised ,growth oriented stable coin which ensures stable continuous and inclusive growth for all the participants, on-chain daily audit, 100 e-Paise equals to 1 e-Rupiya, Trustless, increasing trust base for the newly developed blockchain which ensures vedic maths and Q# language utilisation in blockchain development, interoperability and parellal multi chain support, resist ASIC usage, DEX and triangular arbitrage support, minimum transaction fees, easiest setup
